# User plugin. Set relation after create a model

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I customize User plugin by Rainlabs.

A User model has relation with user groups. After I create a user I want set his user group (guest, registered etc).

It's not working:

```
// also tried beforeCreate
public function afterCreate()
{
    if (something)
       // groups is a relation field name
       $this->groups = 'guest'; // guest is a user group code
    else
       $this->groups = 'registered';
}
```

Comment: are you writing in the User Model ? you will lose your code if plugin gets update

Comment: I second Zakir's statement. You should extend the User's plugin instead of customizing the user plugin. If you did this your custom code will be erased when the User's plugin is updated.

Comment: @Pettis Brandon thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
// User model
public function afterCreate() {
    $this->groups()->add(UserGroup::where('code', 'registered')->first());
    ...
}
```